# Перестал работать Lazy Load Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, lazyloading

Браузер начал выдавать ошибку LazyLoadXT not a function [image: введите сюда описание изображения]и [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Развернули backup, этих ошибок нет, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Нарушен порядок загрузки скриптов. Ответить нельзя точнее, ибо никто не знает, что у вас за lazyloadxt, откуда она берётся, из какого плагина.

Comment: Плагин a3 Lazy Load

Comment: А код, обрывок которого вы нам показали, как запускается?

Comment: Это скрин из ошибки, который показал браузер, этот кусок кода находится в плагине Lazy Load

Comment: Сравните сайт до бекапа и после - что вы там сделали такого, что плагин перестал работать. Само по себе ничего не случается.